# My first scrapy xpath selector

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am very new at this and have been trying to get my head around my first selector. Can somebody help me? I am trying to extract data from this page:

> [http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc-*-ghs-d1-*-asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215337195041/1/so_false](http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc-_-ghs-d1-_-asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215337195041/1/so_false)

all the info under div class = listing clearfix shelfListing but I can't seem to figure out how to format `response.xpath()`.

I have managed to launch the scrapy console but no matter what I type in `response.xpath()` I can't seem to select the right node. I know it works because when I type

```
>>>response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]')
```

I get a response. Yet, I don't know how to navigate to the listsing cleardix shelflisting. I am hoping that once I get this bit I can continue working my way through the spider.

PS I wonder if it is not possible to scan this site - is it possible for the owners to block spiders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content inside the `div` with `listings` class (and `id`) is loaded via an XHR request asynchronously. In other words, the html code that `Scrapy` gets doesn't contain it:

```
$ scrapy shell http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215337195041/1/so_false
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="listings"]')
[]
```

Using browser developer tools, you can see the request going to http://groceries.asda.com/api/items/viewitemlist url with a bunch of GET parameters.

One option would be to simulate that request and parse the resulting JSON:

[image]

How to do it is actually a part of a different question.

---

Here's one possible solution using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) package:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc--ghs-d1--asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/1215337195041/1/so_false')

div = driver.find_element_by_id('listings')
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="listings"]//a[@title]'):
    print item.text.strip()

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
Kellogg's Coco Pops
Kelloggs Rice Krispies
Kellogg's Coco Pops Croco Copters
...
```

Comment: Hi Alecxe,  thank you very much for clearing that up. I thought I was going man with the X path variants that I was trying. So you suggestion is to use some tool that actually caches the page and then extract the data from this?  Do you have any in mind? Thanks again.

Comment: @JaspalSinghRathour well, yeah, another option would be to use tools like `selenium` that fire up a real browser and basically provide you with What you see is what you get. Would you be ok with using a real browser here?

Comment: I guess that would be one approach. See if I can export the source and then run a script that searches for tags or regular expressions. Ultimately I would like to automate the query to run daily and populate an sql database,  but I guess I am a few strides away from that :)

Comment: @JaspalSinghRathour so, two approaches I suggest: first, preferred one - simulate the get request in python (using `requests` module, for example) and parse the data from the json response. And another one, use `selenium` and extract the data from the HTML source code. Choose one and I would try to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Hi alecxe I would very much like to go for option 1 as this seems like the most fluid of the two. I am not a python expert but will be delighted at the right pointers.  As you know the objective is to pull out product info from the page and inputting into json or csv would be great so that it can then be inserted into a database.

Comment: Essentially I just want to pull out product title, weight, wasprice and price for all items within the first container. If there is a way of advancing to the next element then that would be great. Thank you very much in advance this is a great help.

Comment: @JaspalSinghRathour I've added the example code for the 2nd option (using selenium). Sorry, too drunk to complete the 1st solution - things are not that obvious there :)

Comment: Hi Alecxe, thank you so much!!! All I need to do now is figure out how to get the xpaths for  weight, wasprice and price. If you are online (which you probably are not) it would be great if you could tell me what these are. If not I will try and figure them out and how to insert all values into an array.

Comment: Hi Alecxe, figured it out. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. Once again thank you for your very timely help!!

Comment: Thanks alecxe I have posted another question under the loops topic that might be an easy one for you if you are still awake!